# PL/SQL block running without printing any output

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, plsql, dbms

I'm trying to exexcute a pl/sql block using dbms_output to obtain a console output but without reason the unique answer by SQL developer is 'Anonymous block finished'.

```
declare
    v_count integer;
    lines dbms_output.chararr;
    num_lines number;
 begin
    dbms_output.ENABLE;
    num_lines := 0;

    for r in (select table_name, owner from all_tables
              where owner = 'SYSAME'
              and table_name like 'SYZ%'
              and table_name not in (select distinct table_name from all_tab_columns
                                      where OWNER = 'SYSAME'
                                      and table_name like '%SYZ%'
                                      and column_name not like '%FL_IDE_FILIALE%')) 

    loop
        execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || r.table_name || ' where fl_ide_filiale = 12' 
            into v_count;
        dbms_output.Put_line(r.table_name ||';'|| r.owner ||';'|| v_count ||';'|| SYSDATE );    
        num_lines := num_lines + 1; 
    end loop;

    dbms_output.get_lines(lines, num_lines);
    dbms_output.Put_line(num_lines);

    FOR i IN 1..num_lines LOOP
      dbms_output.Put_line(lines(i));
    END LOOP; 

end;
```

Any idea why i don't obtain any output ?

**Q2:** is there any way to plot the output not with a string line and in a table-like way. In this case someting like a select with this values : 
`r.table_name, r.owner, v_count, SYSDATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aswering Question2:

You can't show the result like Sql Server when you build an anonymous block in PL-SQL. You have to do it using procedure or function.
ps: function must return a sys_refcursor.

But hey, I had similar problem... What I've done for this case was to make a stored procedure to pass a string of values and show it like a table using simple math and drawing techniques. (I don't have the stored procedure, it was from my previous work)

Answer (score 1):

You must run `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` before you execute the PL/SQL script.